# Sequelize.define is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've recently started to play around with node.js so i am new to this. I'm getting the following error in my node.js console [Can't upload images yet apparently because of my rating, please click the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN0OI.png)

Below is my code.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const dbConfig = new Sequelize('Mike_Test', 'sa', '[DBPASSWORD]', {
host:'179.27.69.555',
dialect: 'mssql',
port: 1433,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
},

});
//Model Schhema
function createDB(){
var Customer2 = Sequelize.define('Customers2', {


Name: {
Name: Sequelize.STRING, 
allowNull: false
},
Email: {
Email: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false 
}, 
Phone: {
Phone: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false
},
Webiste: {
Webiste: Sequelize.STRING, 
allowNull: true  
},
Message: {
Message: Sequelize.STRING, 
allowNull: true 
},
createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,



})
//Creates DB if it does not exist already.
Customer2.sync({force:true}).then(function() {

//Add to Cstomers2 Table
Customer2.create({Name: "Michael Sony", Email: 
"michael@locationextreme.com", Phone: "01865657000", Website: 
"https://www.youtbe.com", Message: "Blah Blah Blah!"})
});

};

createDB();
```

I have connected to a DB [Customers] with the above connection details successfully, but I can't create a new database and write to it [Customers2]

**Changed code**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const dbConfig = new Sequelize('Mike_Test', 'sa', 'Georged0g', {
host:'172.27.60.139',
dialect: 'mssql',
port: 1433,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
},

});
//Model Schhema
function createDB(){
var Customer2 = dbConfig.define('Customers2', {


Name: {
Name: Sequelize.STRING, 
allowNull: false
},
Email: {
Email: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false 
}, 
Phone: {
Phone: Sequelize.STRING,
allowNull: false
},
Webiste: {
Webiste: Sequelize.STRING, 
allowNull: true  
},
Message: {
Message: Sequelize.STRING, 
allowNull: true 
},
createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,



})
//Creates DB if it does not exist already.
Customer2.sync({force:true}).then(function() {

//Add to Cstomers2 Table
Customer2.create({Name: "Michael Sony", Email: 
"michael@locationextreme.com", Phone: "01865657000", Website: 
"https://www.youtbe.com", Message: "Blah Blah Blah!"})
});

};

createDB();
```

Comment: it's not `dbConfig.define(...)` instead?

Comment: Hi, thank you I'm no longer getting the above error now. Indeed I should have been using dbConfig.define! I'm now getting another error. "throw new Error(Unrecognised data type for field ' + name);" "Error: Unrecognised data type for field Name" Surley  Name: Sequelize..STRING is a valid datatype?

Comment: Did you replace `Sequelize.STRING` by `dbConfig.STRING`? If so, rollback your modifications except for `dbConfig.define`

Comment: I've posted my changed code, I only made the one chnage "dbConfig.define" and I now get "throw new Error(Unrecognised data type for field ' + name);" "Error: Unrecognised data type for field Name"

Comment: Ok, I got it, replace all `[field]: Sequelize.TYPE` by `type: Sequelize.TYPE`. type is not TYPE in lowercase, it's litterally type

Comment: Of course!!! You're a gentleman and a scholar! Thank you! As mentioned previously I'm new to node.js and was boxed in with my code I couldn't see the syntax mistake! Even though it was right in front of my face! Thank you once again.